# Typescript doesn't throw error in .d.ts files

Tags: typescript, types

I have a `*.d.ts` files with the following content.

```js
declare var a: SomeType;
```

I have not declared a type named `SomeType` anywhere, still, there is no error here instead typescript automatically interprets it as `any`. Changing the extension of the file from `*.d.ts` to `*.ts` there is an error.

Why is that? Is there something I can do so that typescript throws errors in `*.d.ts` files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, this was happening because I had `"skipLibCheck": true` in my `tsconfig.json`. Turning it to `false` fixed this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is intentional maybe [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36971) GitHub Issue will help you to better understand why that happens